# Invalid Cast on incomming strings

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a class that is being populated by data. not all datatypes are strings:

```
public class NDCContract
{
    public string ndc_id { get; set; }
    public string contract_num_val { get; set; }
    public string quote_price { get; set; }
    public string eff_dt { get; set; }
    public string end_dt { get; set; }
    public string discount_pct { get; set; }
    public string rebate_pct { get; set; }
}
```

I have a service calling a stored procedure that returns something like this via a JOIN:

[image]

Then my code is looped through to populate a list:

```
                var ndccont = new List<BusinessObjects.Models.NDCContract>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var item = new BusinessObjects.Models.NDCContract();
                    item.ndc_id = reader.GetString(0);
                    item.contract_num_val = reader.GetString(1);
                    item.quote_price = reader.GetString(2);
                    item.eff_dt = reader.GetString(3);
                    item.end_dt = reader.GetString(4);
                    item.discount_pct = reader.GetString(5);
                    item.rebate_pct = reader.GetString(6);
                    ndccont.Add(item);
                }
```

On the line `item.quote_price = reader.GetString(2);` I am getting the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.`

Why when the property is a string and it's read in as a string am I getting this error? How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `reader[2].ToString()` instead, the value you receive from the db is not a string but a decimal.

Comment: Are you sure that column 2 (i.e the third one) isn't a `decimal`? And if it is a decimal, why would you convert it to a `string`?

Comment: Can you please clarify which part of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx "No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string." is causing confusion?

Comment: I feared that in database all columns were strings. But if they (thanks god) have proper types - why you use all strings for your model?

Comment: @Evk OP clearly stated "not all datatypes are strings". So some are bound to fail on conversion to string given the code in the post...

Comment: Why don't you use the correct data types for each property?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes but I mean if quote_price is proper decimal in database (as we see), why is it string in NDCContract?

Comment: @Evk because storing non-string values as strings is more interesting? Like `1,234` as you've commented on an answer or `10/11/12` for date are awesome examples - make life less boring. :) Well known practice - [stringly typed code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just retrieve your fields using `Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(i))`.

`reader.GetString(int)` does not perform any type conversion.

---

## Specifying a culture

If you want to provide your own culture instead of the current one, you can specify it using the [System.Globalization.CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
// Note the second argument
string value = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Note that this conversion depends on current culture, which might have unexpected consequences.

Comment: @Evk Good catch. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, so there is a `quote_price` and a `discount_pct`. How would one multiply those two?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That's another question for another problem

Comment: @KrisVandermotten that's easy - just decimal.Parse and multiply.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your model correctly. I don't know for sure what the data types in the database are, but they are probably something like this:

```
public class NDCContract
{
    public string ndc_id { get; set; }
    public string contract_num_val { get; set; }
    public decimal quote_price { get; set; }
    public DateTime eff_dt { get; set; }
    public DateTime  end_dt { get; set; }
    public decimal discount_pct { get; set; }
    public decimal rebate_pct { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate the structure correctly:

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var item = new BusinessObjects.Models.NDCContract();
                item.ndc_id = reader.GetString(0);
                item.contract_num_val = reader.GetString(1);
                item.quote_price = reader.GetDecimal(2);
                item.eff_dt = reader.GetDateTime(3);
                item.end_dt = reader.GetDateTime(4);
                item.discount_pct = reader.GetDecimal(5);
                item.rebate_pct = reader.GetDecimal(6);
                ndccont.Add(item);
            }
```